# how can the color a material select border be changes?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, material-design

I'm trying to change the color of the border of a material select.
I tried doing changing the border color using css from:
[image]
to this:
[image]
How could it be done?

thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it using these style rules:

```
/* Chaning the color of the bottom border of the material select */
.mat-form-field-underline.ng-tns-c166-0.ng-star-inserted {
    filter: invert(1);
}

/* Chaning the color of the arrow icon included into the mterial select*/
.mat-select-arrow.ng-tns-c169-1 {
    color: black;
}
```

I am only wondering if there are other ways to do it.